# Firebase Cloud Firestore query with regex workaround

Tags: ios, swift, regex, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my app the user should be able to search other users that are stored in Firebase. Pretty much like Instagram for example. Tragically I found out that this is not quite possible in Firebase yet. Most of the posts I found about this were older, so was there anything added that could help me out here?

I thought about this:

Right now I have stored all`users with their information. When starting the app I could retrieve *all usernames*  and store it in a variable and then work with that. But this is rather brute force approach... I figure I am not the only one with that problem, so does anyone know what I can do here?

I hope this question is conforming all guidelines, correct me if not.

Comment: I see the question was closed but why do you think you can't query in Firebase? It has extraordinarily fast query engine and querying is covered in the Firestore documentation [Queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries)

Answer (score 1):

If Firestore isn't adequate for the kinds of queries you want to perform, your only real alternative is to duplicate that data into another database that can do it.

You will have to come up with some options on your own, as requests for offsite software products are off-topic for Stack Overflow.